# non updateble variable declaration within a function

Tags: python, variables, computer-vision

i want to create a function that helps calculate the speed of a detected and tracked object , the idea is to calculate the distance between two points p1 and p2 the problem is that p2 have save the previous object location and p1 is the actual object location.
how can I introduce p2 in the function without getting initialized every time.
i tried to declare it as a global variable outside the function but it doesn't work " error: p2 is not defined "

```
def draw_box_label(img, bbox_cv2, box_color=(0, 255, 255), show_label=True):

'''
Helper funciton for drawing the bounding boxes and the labels
bbox_cv2 = [left, top, right, bottom]
'''

##sagem begin
global p1   
p1=[]


##sagem end
#box_color= (0, 255, 255)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
font_size = 0.7
font_color = (0, 0, 0)
left, top, right, bottom = bbox_cv2[1], bbox_cv2[0], bbox_cv2[3], bbox_cv2[2]

#sagem begin 
p1.append((left+right)/2)
p1.append((top+bottom)/2)

#sagem end

# Draw the bounding box
cv2.rectangle(img, (left,top), (right, bottom), box_color, 4)

if show_label:
    # Draw a filled box on top of the bounding box (as the background for the labels)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (left-2, top-45), (right+2, top), box_color, -1, 1)
    

    # speed
    if p2!=[]:

        surface=calculate_surface(img, bbox_cv2)
        scale=calculate_scale(surface)
        #Calculate the speed in pixels
        speed=round(calculate_speed(p1,p2,scale))
        #output the speed 
        text_s=str(speed)+"km/h"
        cv2.putText(img,text_s,(left,top-10), font, font_size, font_color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Output the labels that show the x and y coordinates of the bounding box center.
    
    #text_x= 'x='+str((left+right)/2)
    #cv2.putText(img,text_x,(left,top-25), font, font_size, font_color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    #text_y= 'y='+str((top+bottom)/2)
    #cv2.putText(img,text_y,(left,top-5), font, font_size, font_color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)  
##sagem begin

p2=p1

##sagem end
return img
```

Comment: please use code (text) instead of pictures. also reduce the problem as much as possible.

Comment: if this p2 have a know value, you can pass it as your argument

Comment: also ask yourself, what value should this p2 have the very first time if what it represent is the previous know location

Comment: the value of p2 have to be the previous value of p1 if i declare inside the function p2 is going to reintialized whenver the function is executed and if i declare it outside the function it's gonna be unknown and i'm gonna have an error